# JS: body tag onload equivalent?

Tags: javascript

I need to basically add this to my page:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('WeddingBandBuilder').focus()">
```

However due to my template I cannot change the  tag. So is there a way to do the equivalent with a script in the < head > tag or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('WeddingBandBuilder').focus()};
</script>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using an addLoadEvent type structure, to avoid interfering with existing code.  http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/

Answer (score 0):

You should always be careful there isn't already a `window.onload` defined. I've been burned a number of times by assuming I would be the only one attaching things to `<body onload="...">` or `window.onload`.

See [this answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load/807997#807997) for a solution to this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Use a JS library like jQuery or Prototype and create an external script file with something like this:

for jQuery:

```
$(function() { $('#WeddingBandBuilder').focus(); });
```

for Prototype:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() { $('WeddingBandBuilder').focus(); });
```

Comment: Did he say he was using a JavaScript library? No. I'm so tired of JavaScript questions getting library answers when they didn't ask for it. If someone asks for a question in Python do people just drop in some Django crap? Also if he can't edit the body tag what makes you think he can add a JavaScript library and why would he want to add one just so he can do this tiny thing.

Comment: @apphacker
1. He said he can edit the head tag.
2. Python/Django don't quite compare to this situation because a big part of the appeal of these libraries is that they bring some sanity into browser differences.
3. window.onload = whatever; in the head might easily break, using a library won't.

Comment: @nouveau, I don't know much about JS, I am mainly a Actionscript and PHP programmer. But this site is a pretty decent size ecommerce site, is it possible that adding jquery could effect anything in a negative way? Thanks

Comment: I tried window.onload = whatever; but It didn't work. The reason I need this is because a flex app wont show in IE until it is moused over...setting focus is a work around.

Comment: @john Isaacks, yes using a JavaScript library in the middle of an existing site can cause problems.

Comment: And just for the record I'm a big Dojo fan and use Dojo for just about everything, but I don't add Dojo answers for non Dojo questions.

Answer (score -2):

I might check if that page has already included jQuery?  If so, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#WeddingBandBuilder').focus();
});
```